# How to pass Event emitter's value from child component to parents component's function as an argument?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting 'date' returned from child event emitter, I am trying to pass the returned 'date' as an argument to a function to my parent's component, and that function needs to be initialized when the page loads so that I can crate the template view. I attempted the following but I couldn't find a way to pass the value as an argument of my "getData()" function on page load. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**parentComponent.html**

```
<child (todaysDate)="getTodaysDate($event)"></child>
```

**parentComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './parentComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './parentComponent.component.css' ]
})
export class parentComponent implements OnInit  {
 getTodaysDate(todaysDate){
 this.getData(todaysDate)

}

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

getData(todaysDate){
///subscribe data from api
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Child component

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() todaysDate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.todaysDate.emit(new Date());
   }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the value returned from child, but having difficulty passing the value to the function I have in parent component, in order to load data when parent component gets  initialized based on the 'date' returned from child

Comment: `ngOninit() {this.todaysDate.emit(new Date());}` that what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the parent component initializes first and then the child component. So the order of execution will be for instance,

Parent Constructor --> Child Constructor --> Parent OnInit --> Child OnInit

So, by the time we emit value from child component, the parent component would have been initialized.
So if you want to send values from child component to parent component and update the parent component view `onInit`, I propose an alternate solution as below.

1. Create a `BehaviorSubject` in child component. Initialize with value.
2. Get the `BehaviorSubject` value from `ChildComponent` using `@ViewChild` decorator and `subscribe` to it in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. In the subscribe callback function, update the parent template.
3. Run the `detectChanges()` from `ChangeDetectorRef` after updating the parent template.

   I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7z2vzq?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.ts) example for this scenario. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

In angular, parent get loaded then child components.
You could trigger your event emitter right away in the onInit method in your child component:

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() todaysDate: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
   
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.getNewDate();
   }

   getNewDate() {
       this.todaysDate.emit(new Date());
   }
}
```

In your parent, you'll trigger a subject on your child event and create an observable that will get your data, with your subject as a source, in the onInit method:

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {
 
 myData$: Observable<any>;
 newDate$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
 
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.myData$ = this.newDate$.pipe(
         switchMap(newDate => this.getData(newDate))
     );
 }

 getTodaysDate(todaysDate){
     this.newDate$.next(todaysDate);
 }

 getData(todaysDate){
     //subscribe data from api
 }
}
```

Then, you'll subscribe to your myData$ observable in the parent template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of myData$ | async">
    <!-- Print your data in template -->
</div>
```

Like this, each time you load your parent, your data will get pulled off on child event.